# maximize $v_0 x+ v_1 y$ s.t. $ (x/a)^2+(y/b)^2 =1$

Tags: optimization, vectors

How to maximize the dot product of two vectors, one is fixed, the other is constrained on an ellipse?

i.e., how to maximize
$$
v_0 x+ v_1 y
$$
s.t.
$$
\left(\frac{x}{a} \right)^2 +\left(\frac{y}{b} \right)^2=1
$$

intuitively, let $x=a \sin t, y= b \cos t$, then the limit occurs when the tangent
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \cos t \\
-b \sin t \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is orthogonal to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_0 \\
v_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e.
$$
v_0 a \cos t= v_1 b \sin t
$$
Thus, the maximum point is
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{a^2 v_0}{ \sqrt{ a^2 v_0^2 +b^2 v_1^2 }} \\
y=\frac{b^2 v_1}{ \sqrt{ a^2 v_0^2 +b^2 v_1^2 }}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without multipliers:**

Let $x=a\cos t,y=b\sin t$ and maximize

$$v_0a\cos t+v_1b\sin t=\sqrt{(v_0a)^2+(v_1b)^2}\cos(t-\phi).$$

Obviously, the maximum is

$$\sqrt{(v_0a)^2+(v_1b)^2}.$$